# console.log says success for each call but twiiter not showing retweets

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, twitter

help!
im trying to call this function but not working how i anticipated

```
var T = new Twit(config);
var retweet = function() {

T.get('search/tweets', {q:'#python3, #nodejs, python3, nodejs,', count :5 }, 
function(err, data, response){
    const t_ID = data.statuses[0].id_str
    const t_ID_1 = data.statuses[1].id_str
    const t_ID_2 = data.statuses[2].id_str
    const t_ID_3 = data.statuses[3].id_str
    console.log(t_ID, t_ID_1, t_ID_2, t_ID_3)
    console.log(data)
    T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: t_ID }, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log('Posted')

      })
      T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: t_ID_1 }, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log('Posted_1')
        
      })
      T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: t_ID_2 }, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log('Posted_2')
      })
      T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: t_ID_3 }, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log('Posted_3')
      })    
} )
}
    retweet();

     setInterval(retweet, 80000);`
enter code here
```

console.log shows

Posted_1
Posted
Posted_3
Posted_2

but twitter is not retweeting or will retweet two and next time none, then retweet 3.

plus code is messy can anyone optimize and solve my bug?

Comment: What is the actual response you are getting from the Post requests? They might tell you what is going on.

Comment: status: '403 Forbidden',

Comment: this same script was working earlier with no issues, what is a better way to send post request for multiple id's?

Answer (score 0):

my issue was when i query "#python3, #nodejs, python3, nodejs"  all in the same call only a limited amount of tweets return that include all of those paramaters given, which caused me to retweet all results.

i solved this by limiting only 1 paramater per call and create a new function for another paramater i wish to search.

```
var T = new Twit(config);
var retweet = function() {

T.get('search/tweets', {q:'#python3', count :5 }, 
function(err, data, response){
    const t_ID = data.statuses[0].id_str
    console.log(t_ID)
    T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', { id: t_ID }, function (err, data, response) {
        console.log('You have RT-d post about JS')
        console.log(response.header.status)
})    
} )
}
    retweet();
     setInterval(retweet, 80000);`
```

and console log returns tweet_id_str, success message(You have RT-d post about JS), and my status. if status return 200 i had success, if 403 i did not.

- You have RT-d post about JS
  -1312731838457106432
  -200 OK